# Executing Firebird stored procedure using JOOQ

Tags: java, sql, database, stored-procedures, jooq

I have firebird database, and create java project that use it. By using GenerationTool I generate database structure. When i tried execute statement like this all works fine.

```
Result<Record1<Integer>> toStations = create.select(STATIONS.STATION_ID).
                    from(STATIONS).
                    where(STATIONS.CITY_ID.equal(create.select(CITIES.CITY_ID).
                            from(CITIES).
                            where(CITIES.CITY_NAME.equal(to)))).fetch();
```

But I can not execute stored procedure. I have stored procedure:

```
create or alter procedure Find_Schemes (
    FROM_STATION ID not null,
    TO_STATION ID not null)
returns (
    SCHEME_ID ID)
as
begin
  for select SCHEME_ID
      from SCHEMES S
      where PATH_ID = (select PATH_ID
                       from PATHES P
                       where PATH_ID = S.PATH_ID and
                             (select LIST_POS
                              from PATHES_STATIONS
                              where PATH_ID = P.PATH_ID and
                                    STATION_ID = :FROM_STATION) < (select LIST_POS
                                                                   from PATHES_STATIONS
                                                                   where PATH_ID = P.PATH_ID and
                                                                         STATION_ID = :TO_STATION))
      into :SCHEME_ID
  do
  begin
    suspend;
  end
end
^
```

I tried execute him like this

```
Result result = (Result) Routines.findSchemes(7,22);
            System.out.println(result);
```

but I have exception than I can't cast this to (Result);

Then I tried do this, but this not work to because findSchemes need String parameters, but in my procedure only Integer parameters:

```
Result result = create.select(FIND_SCHEMES(7,22));
```

How I can execute Firebird procedure using JOOQ?

Comment: You should always append your exception trace if any

Comment: You can't `select` from a stored procedure. You need to use a function that returns a result set. Or you need a procedure call that handles cursors (don't know JOOQ, so I can't tell you how to do it there - would be pretty simple in plain JDBC)

Answer (score 1):

After 3 hours by typing random commands it works.

```
Result result = create.selectFrom(Routines.findSchemesWithInfo(7, 22)).fetch();

System.out.println(result);
+---------+----------+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
|SCHEME_ID|START_CITY|END_CITY       |DISTANCE|TRAVEL_TIME|COMFORT_LVL|HAND_LUGGAGE|LUGGAGE|
+---------+----------+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
|        1|Київ      |Миколаїв       |     189|        193|Преміум    |      {null}| {null}|
|        2|Київ      |Кіровоград     |     189|        193|Преміум    |      {null}| {null}|
|        3|Київ      |Кіровоград     |     189|        193|Преміум    |      {null}| {null}|
|        4|Київ      |Дніпропетровськ|     189|        193|Преміум    |      {null}| {null}|
+---------+----------+---------------+--------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: This is how it works, indeed. For future visitors of this question, [the relevant page of the jOOQ manual is the one about table valued functions](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/table-valued-functions/)